# ZipArchive::extractTo does nothing

Tags: php, zip, unzip, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to extract a zip file to an existing folder on my PHP file directory using this code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

It shows everything is fine, I see the `ok` message on the screen from the `echo` command, but the folder still stays empty.
The folder exists in the direct path, everything is correct, but it still doesn't work.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file show?

Comment: I don't know exactly what that is. I'm working with XAMPP. I'm new to PHP

Comment: The apache http server write a few log files in background. You can consult the documentation for the details. One of those is the error log file. That is where you can _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_ or ask. The typical location is something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log` on unixoid systems. Check your http servers configuration for the `ErrorLog` directive to find the exact location.

Comment: A general hint: you _cannot_ develop php in a web environment without monitoring that log file. That would be like flying blindfolded in a narrow cave.

Comment: Just a wild shot, but most likely this is the result of missing permissions to access the target folder for the process executing the php script.

Comment: @arkascha OK, I checked the logs, but there is nothing in there about it

Comment: @arkascha I don't think this is about permissions, since I'm working on Windows 7, and I'm not having any permission-related problems on any other files

Comment: I am not familiar with MS-Windows based operating systems, but even though they are not multi user systems I would expect system services to be executed under another account. That implies file system permission issues.

Comment: About the issue at hand: you will have to start debugging. First thing obviously to do is check the return values of calls to methods like `ZipArchive::extractTo()`. Does it _really_ return `true` as documented? http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php Best is to log such things into an application log file you monitor permanently by something like the `tail` utility or similar.

Comment: Oh, and another thing that just strikes me odd... You apparently left the target path `/my/destination/dir/` when copying the example code. Whilst php is fine with normal forward slashes as folder separators even on MS-Windows based systems I dare say that a folder `/my` certainly does _not_ exist in your system. So how should that extraction succeed?

Comment: @arkascha I copied it straight from the example on PHP documentation. In my code I have the real path

Comment: So what you posted is _not_ your actual code? Sorry, but please change that. `edit` your question, place that example code with your real code. If necessary replace things like paths and names, but do not post unrelated code!

Comment: @arkascha It is related code! It's just the path, but in the code the path is correct

Comment: Ok, fine then. So what do you answer to my other questions?

Comment: And one more remark about the code being sample code: Please modify it to show the actual path you use for the function call. Chances are you are accidentally using an invalid path due to how php (and most other languages) handles string notations if you are using a standard MS-Windows path notation like `C:\some\path`. Use normal forward slashes as folder separators to make sure the target path actually exists or implement an additional check testing if that path actually exists from the perspective of php.